# Sharing data between two test cases in google test framework

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm testing a particular implementation of a algorithm with random input data using google test framework. I want to use the same random input data for another implementation of the same algorithm. I'm testing the two implementation using two separate test cases. Is there a way to share the random input data from one test case to another.

Comment: Create a test fixture.

Comment: Use the same RNG algorithm and seed?

Comment: @user4581301 using the same RNG algorithm and seed helped.

Comment: It is not possible by design. Each test case should be be isolated from each other. Moreover - changing the order in which test cases run should not cause any problems - meaning if TEST1 run before or after TEST2 should always have the same result. Look at FIRST principles to get explanation how to write good unit tests. Of course you can be break this good programming practices by using global variables...

Answer (score 11):

Look at this section "Sharing Resources Between Tests in the Same Test Case" in https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite

Following static methods in your test fixture class :

```
static void SetUpTestCase()

static void TearDownTestCase()
```

serve for acquisition and release of shared resources, respectively.

Of course the member variables representing that shared objects must be defined as static members of your test fixture class (static methods have access only to static members). Don't forget global variable like declaration of those members (compiler throws error if you do not declare them like that).

`SetUpTestCase()` is called by Google Test Framework before execution of the first test and `TearDownTestCase()` after execution of the last one.

Everything I mentioned is comprehensively described in above reference. There is also example there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Test Fixture](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests) as explained in the documentation:

```
TEST_F(test_case_name, test_name) {
 ... test body ...
}
```

Test Fixtures keep the data that was created using the `SetUp()` function, between runs of your test cases as it was modified.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm already using TEST_F. But I want to share data between two TEST_F., is it possible ? Documentation says SetUp will instantiate each test case.